# Higher-level Web Page I/O with javascript (analogous to file I/O with shell scripts)?

Tags: javascript, dom, io, screen-scraping

**What I am trying to do (no alternative suggestions please, I know more conventional solutions)** Easily scrape data from web pages such as images without writing any site-specific code (e.g. to get the biggest image at a particular URL). This is just ONE possibility.

**What I'm dreaming of (for other uses too)**
I know you can scrape using many APIs that use a DOM model. But surely someone's thought of something higher level? One of the most attractive things about shell script is the data manipulation you can do with basic file I/O with basic commands: Grep plus regular expressions (awk, sed, perl) can instantly put you in touch with goldmines of file-based data. What shell scripts are to files, javascript should be to web pages. But code gets so messy when you address things by tags and attributes. Wouldn't it be wonderful if there was some kind of API like this?

```
# determine the biggest image by checking images[0].height etc.
$("< http://www.cnn.com/man-has-three-eyes.html").images[0].url
```

Has such an API ever been attempted? I'm guessing not. If not, what makes this technically unrealistic? If so, what kind of javascript frameworks are the closest thing to offering this?

(If it doesn't, I should file for trademark protection on the brand name "Scrapy Eye" or "ScrAPI" or something!)

Comment: Did you try headless browsers such as http://phantomjs.org?

Comment: Oh, no I try javascript-based headless browsers (only java). I didn't realize that was possible. I'm looking at PhantomJS now but I don't see an easy way to determine all the images in a page. Do you see it anywhere? Or another framework that does it?

Comment: See the "code evaluation" section [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Quick-Start). Once you get the document object, you can get the first image URL with document.images[0].src, like on any browser.